# Symfony Serializer Component: Can you prioritise a has method instead of get?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the [Symfony Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) to serialize an entity before returning it within an API response.

My understanding is that this uses [ObjectNormalizer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/ObjectNormalizer.php) to process the entity before returning it as JSON. I am also using `@Groups` annotations to specify what properties need to be returned within the API response.

Controller method:

```
 /**
  * @Rest\Get("/foo")
  * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"basic"})
  *
  * @return View
  */
  public function index(): View
  {
      $allFoo = $this->fooRepository->findAll();
        
      return View::create($allFoo, Response::HTTP_OK);
  }
```

Entity:

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $bar;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getBar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setBar(string $bar): self
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     *
     * @Groups({"basic"})
     */
    public function hasBar(): bool
    {
        return (!is_null($this->bar));
    }
}
```

The response I would expect would be:

```
[
  {
    "bar": true
  },
  {
    "bar": false
  }
]
```

But the response I am getting is:

```
[
  {
    "bar": "Foo"
  },
  {
    "bar": null
  }
]
```

It looks like `ObjectNormalizer` is looking for a getter first, and then a hasser even though the `@Groups` anotation is on the hasser. The Symfony docs also state that "If there is no getter found, the accessor will look for an isser or hasser." [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#using-hassers-issers).

I can not remove the get method and renaming the has method would break the code convention within the project.

How can you prioritise a has method over a get without creating a custom normalizer?

Comment: Don't think so. alternatives: 1. custom repository method returning arrays, or 2. use normalize, fix bools, use encode ... instead of serialize (=normalize+encode). both approaches somewhat display in code what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I ran into this today and will add my answer for posterity.

I have an Entity with a `$password` field. This field is not normally allowed to be read via the API (only written), but I want the API to return true/false if its defined.

The trick is using `@SerializerName` on the `has` method. The serialized name and method name must not conflict with the actual property name (eg: don't call it `hasPassword()`

```php
    /**
     * @Encrypted
     * @Groups({"item:write"})
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected ?string $password = null;

    /**
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @SerializedName("hasPassword")
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasRealPassword(): bool
    {
        return $this->password !== null;
    }
```

The serialized result will now have a `hasPassword` field:

```json
{
  ...,
  "hasPassword: true,
}
```